# How can I add new column in Julia Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, julia

Let's say I have dataframe and vector such as :

```
dataframe = DataFrame(Data1 = rand(10), Data2 = rand(10));
Data3 = rand(10)
```

I want to add `Data3` to the dataframe such as:

```
    Data1       Data2     Data3
    Float64     Float64   Float64
1   0.757345    0.903133  0.502133
2   0.294749    0.327502  0.323133
3   0.156397    0.427323  0.123133
```

In Python, I can just `df["Data3"] = Data3` to add column, but in Julia dataframe, `df[!,Data3] = Data3` returns :

- *MethodError: no method matching setindex!(::DataFrame, ::Vector{Float64}, ::typeof(!), ::Vector{Float64})*

Also I've checked [this solution](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/adding-a-new-row-to-a-dataframe/1331), but this gave me :

- *ArgumentError: syntax df[column] is not supported use df[!, column] instead*.

How can I add vector as a new column in Julia Dataframe?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were almost there, you are looking for:

```
dataframe[!, :Data3] = Data3
```

or

```
dataframe[!, "Data3"] = Data3
```

or

```
dataframe.Data3 = Data3
```

note that I'm using a `Symbol` or `String` here - the `[!, :Data3]` is an indexing operation, so it needs an identifier of the row (`!`) and column (`:Data3`) index where you want the data to be stored, **not** the data itself.

You are binding the actual data (a 10-element vector of random numbers) to the variable `Data3`, so doing `dataframe[!, Data3]` with the variable `Data3` (rather than a `Symbol` or `String` with the value `"Data3"`) is equivalent to doing

```
dataframe[!, rand(10)]
```

which means "I want to access all rows (`!`) of a DataFrame, and 10 columns identified by 10 random numbers". Now indexing by a random floating point number doesn't make a lot of sense (what should `dataframe[!, 0.532]` return?) which is why you get the error you see - `setindex` does not accept a `Vector{Float}` as an argument.

Regarding the Discourse thread you linked, it is very old and the `df["col"]` syntax has been deprecated a long time ago. The basic indexing concept in `DataFrames` is that a `DataFrame` is a two-dimensional data structure, and as such should be indexed by `df[row_indices, col_indices]`.

`DataFrames` supports a variety of ways of specifying valid indices, which are too numerous to go into detail here but are listed in the docs [here](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/stable/lib/indexing/#General-rules).