# Add a column with a constant value to a DataFrame

Tags: julia, dataframes.jl

How can I add a column with a constant value to a DataFrame?

E.g. I have the following DataFrame:

```
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(x = 1:10, y = 'a':'j')
```

And I would like to add a new variable `z` with constant value `1` and obtain:

```
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y     z     
     │ Int64  Char  Int64
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │     1  a         1
   2 │     2  b         1
   3 │     3  c         1
   4 │     4  d         1
   5 │     5  e         1
   6 │     6  f         1
   7 │     7  g         1
   8 │     8  h         1
   9 │     9  i         1
  10 │    10  j         1
```

Comment: oh, sorry, I didn't see it is in Julia. My fault. Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69969780/how-can-i-add-new-column-in-julia-dataframe) will help you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more general alternative is:

```
julia> insertcols!(df, :z => 1)
10×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y     z
     │ Int64  Char  Int64
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │     1  a         1
   2 │     2  b         1
   3 │     3  c         1
   4 │     4  d         1
   5 │     5  e         1
   6 │     6  f         1
   7 │     7  g         1
   8 │     8  h         1
   9 │     9  i         1
  10 │    10  j         1
```

which by default does the same, but it additionally:

1. allows you to specify the location of the new column;
2. by default makes sure that you do not accidentally overwrite an existing column

Comment: What if one would like to overwrite it?

Comment: `df[!, :z] .= 1`

Comment:  I was stupid. I was thinking about your alternative and made this mistake. Anyway, Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

To create such column:

`df = DataFrame(x = 1:10, y = 'a':'j', d = 1)`

To append such column to the existing DataFrame, you need broadcasting:

`df.e .= 1`

or

`df[:, "f"] .= 1`

Comment: Broadcasting the assignment is the trick that I was missing. Thanks!